# IOS storyboard objects

Tags: ios, storyboard

I have my app like below. I am configuring a transition from first scene to the second when the user clicks on rock button, using the rock method(without a segue). But when I run the app I am getting the following error.
Please let me know what the problem is? Is the storyboard object, the label referring to isn't created yet?[image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

Either `secvc` or its `label` property are `nil`. Set a breakpoint on that line and check each's value before that line runs to see which is `nil`.

Comment: I am sure it's the label. I created another instance property of secviewcontroller and used it instead of the label in the rock method, and it worked fine. I just want to know when will be the label object be created in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the text, because the label isn't created yet, this is because the view of your second ViewController isn't loaded at the time your try so set the text of the label

A possible solution would be to add

```
var text: String!
```

in your second View Controller. Set this var in your rock function:

```
secvc.text = "rock ..."
```

and set the text of your label later in the `viewDidLoad()` (the view is now loaded and the label was created) function of your second ViewController:

```
label.text = text
```

Comment: Hey sam thanks for the answer. I did found it is the label. But, could you please explain how the storyboard objects gets created and instantiated. Cause here, since the label object will be loaded from the nib file at the run time, I thought I could use the outlet property to access it.

Comment: I'm a novice in Swift myself, but when you instantiate a ViewController the IBOutlets are not created yet, because the view of the ViewController isn't loaded yet. It gets loaded as soon as you call `self.present(...)`.

Comment: The story board is an XML file.  It is loaded and parsed and then used to instantiate all of the objects in the story board and connect them to the outlets in your ViewController.  This connection is not guaranteed to happen until viewDidLoad gets called.  Thats why in the source controller you set a property (your outlets don't exist yet) then in viewDidLoad (your outlets now exist) you can assign this property to your outlet's .text property.

Answer (score 0):

A nice generic approach is to define a NSDictionary property on a view controller and then you simply set that property from the caller. Then, in the viewDidLoad you can access the dictionary and fill in any widget data from the various fields in the dict. This respects the GUI widget lifetime and makes things easier on you since only data is exchanged. Don't pass refs to any UI* objects in this way and you avoid shooting yourself in the foot with ref count loops.

Comment: More specifically, I'd pass an instance of a class/model to the other view controller instead of a dictionary. MUCH more readable.

Comment: Well, sure a full model object is better, but it also takes longer to make the first revision of the code. A dictionary is at least better than setting specific fields in the view controller that is not even fully constructed yet.